# TexStudio sees the wrong version of TexLive

Tags: texlive, texstudio

When I compile a document from within `TexStudio` on my Linux Mint 17 the software reports:

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "community-detection".tex
```

and the log file starts with:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
```

But when I run exactly the same command from the Terminal I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
```

When I run `Help > Check LaTeX Installation` I get:

```
which pdflatex: /usr/bin/pdflatex
```

but running `which pdflatex` from my Terminal results in:

```
pdflatex is /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
pdflatex is /usr/bin/pdflatex
pdflatex is /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
pdflatex is /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
```

So what is the `/usr/bin/pdflatex` file doing there and which package should I uninstall to get rid of it?

Comment: Just change the path in the options. Also you can uninstall TL 2013 then, unless you like to keep it around.

Comment: How exactly did you (1) Add TL2014 to the `PATH`, (2) Start TeXStudio? If you added `PATH` to `.bashrc` and started `TeXStudio` via a menu, then you are in trouble.

Comment: Use your package manager to remove the TeX Live packages you installed from your distro. (`apt` or whatever.) There are instructions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) for how to configure things e.g. how to install a 'dummy' package to satisfy dependencies.

Comment: @daleif I think you're on the right track. My `.bashrc` contains the line `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`. But I can't see how to set the path for TexStudio.

Comment: You should NEVER set the `PATH` in `.bashrc`. Move it to `.profile`, log out, and log in again. Then it should work. Wehn TeXStudio make a call to latex it does so though a shell, but that shell may never even run `.bashrc`, thus we need something else. Add it to `.profile` and it is set as a *global* variable (and not just a bash variable) and TeXStudio should to good to go. The `.bashrc` thing is a common mistake that we are trying to correct. BTW: where from do you have that you should add the PATH variable to `.bashrc`?

Comment: @daleif My `.bashrc` sins were committed too long ago to remember why I set path in there, but it's all over the internet. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14638008/2071807)'s a prominent example.

Comment: Too many command line jockeys (like myself). If you only use the command line to start your tools bashrc will mostly be fine. But general people are not like that anymore.

Comment: @LondonRob: Added

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many places on the web linux users will find the advise: add blah blah to `PATH` in `~/.bashrc`. In general this is not a good idea, because only when `~/.bashrc` has been executed, is the `PATH` change visible to programmes.

If you are a command line jockey (like me) and open every program through a terminal, you will not see the difference. However, if you start, say, an editor through a menu or a keyboard short cut, then chances are that whenever that editor is going to make a system call to `pdflatex`, it will *not* do this in a manner where `~/.bashrc` has been executed, thus the `PATH` change is not found.

In the case of LaTeX, this often shows up as the editor now using an old LaTeX installation instead of the TeX Live 2014 one had just installed manually.

For Ubuntu based systems the proper solution is

- If this is a single user system: add the `PATH` change to `~/.profile` instead. This is executed *globally* at login.
- If you manage a multi user system, prepend the `PATH` variable found in `/etc/environment` (remember to make a backup of this file, and remember that paths are separated by `:`)

Afterwards log out and log in again.

---

Note: If you plan to login to your Linux box using SSH and then running latex, then it is a good idea to have the PATH change in `.bashrc` as well, as the `.profile` settings are not executed when you login via SSH.