# TeXstudio Error: Could not start the command

Tags: texlive, texstudio, paths

I've installed texlive and add its `/bin` folder to the `PATH` from `.bashrc` file. Both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` commands work well within the terminal; `pdflatex` works from TeXstudio too, but `xelatex` doesn't work from TeXstudio and gives this error:

```
Error: Could not start the command: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "template_Article".tex
```

I changed the build command to use the absolute path to xelatex and it worked fine:

```
"/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

As opposed to `pdflatex` which is invoked by just calling:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

What is the problem in your opinion? TeXstudio version is 2.12.18 and I'm running on TeXLive 2019.

Comment: I'm not using TeXstudio or xelatex, but he part `"template_Article".tex` of the error message is a bit strange to me, I would not expect the `"` at the places they are. I would expect no `"` at all or otherwise `"template_Article.tex"`. This is all a bit of a, wild, guess.

Comment: @albert I copied that to the terminal and it worked just fine; even with the strange place `"` are.

Comment: Maybe related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212225/texstudio-sees-the-wrong-version-of-texlive

Comment: @Marijn Yes, It worked! I removed `PATH` modification from `.bashrc`, added it to `.profile` instead, and did a restart finally.

Comment: Good that it worked, i'll vote to close as a duplicate. I suspect, although I'm not sure, that `pdflatex` was already present on your system from a previous installation while `xelatex` was not, which makes the questions actually duplicate. Maybe this is not true, in that case it would be better to close as 'solved in comments' - but anyway the question can be closed I think.

Comment: @Marijn No, That's not the case; using `which` shows that both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` are placed in the same directory, which is the one I installed this fresh installation of texlive in it.

Comment: @MH.TavakoliBina, ok, but which `which`? If the problem is that the terminal loads different paths than TeXstudio, then `which pdflatex` in the terminal does not tell you much about the executable that TeXstudio uses. Maybe `whereis pdflatex` in the terminal will show more information.

Comment: @Marijn You are right. Using `whereis pdflatex` gives an additional directory compared to `whereis xelatex`, which is `/usr/bin/pdflatex`. Seems like Ubuntu 18.04 has a pre-installed `pdflatex` binary in there.